# Where can I find an English translation of the Taittiriya Shakha of the Krishna Yajur Veda?

Tags: vedas, translation-request, yajur-veda, krishna-yajurveda

Where can I find an English translation of the Taittiriya Shakha of the Krishna Yajur Veda?

[Sacred-texts.com](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/yv/index.htm) only has the Taittiriya Samhita. I want an English translation of the Brahmana and Aranyaka of this Shakha of the Krishna Yajur Veda.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Oh so you're saying the Samhita portion in Sacred Texts has the Brahmana and Aranyaka part included in it?

Comment: @TheDestroyer I don't think so.

Comment: Why Translation? I suggest you to find a Guru and learn from him.

Comment: You can get essence of Taittiriya Aranyaka and Upanishad from kamakoti.org

Comment: @NaveenKick Thanks, I would, but I don't know any Guru, and I live in the US.

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for a free online translation/summary of the Taittirīya Āraṇyaka, there's [*Essence of Taittiriya Aranyaka*](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/books/ESSENCE_OF_TAITTIRIYA_ARANYAKA.pdf) from kamakoti.org.

If you want to purchase in print format, you can try SAKSHI Trust's translations:

- [Taittirīya Āraṇyaka - Volume 1](https://vedah.com/product/taittiriya-aranyaka-volume-1/) (Srikant Jamadagni)
- [Taittirīya Āraṇyaka - Volume 2](https://vedah.com/product/taittiriya-aranyaka-volume-2/) (Srikant Jamadagni)
- [Taittirīya Brāhmaṇa - Volume 1](https://vedah.com/product/taittiriya-brahmana-volume-1/) (R. L. Kashyap)
- [Taittirīya Brāhmaṇa - Volume 2](https://vedah.com/product/taittiriya-brahmana-volume-2/) (R. L. Kashyap)

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for the Aranyaka but came accross your question in that process. I found this source of Krishna Yajur Veda, incl. Samihta, Aranyaka, Brahmana, Kathaka and the pratishakya. Seems very good.

http://www.sanskritweb.net/yajurveda/#EK