# Taittirīya Brāhmaṇa - Whats the difference between Samhita and Brahmana

Tags: vedas, yajur-veda, taittirya-brahmana

Would like to know, whats the difference between Taittirīya Brāhmaṇa and Samhita.

I heard that, in Samhita there are some 44 chapters and contains mantras that includes Srirudram-rudraprasna.( Especially am asking this from the Krishna Yajurveda Context(Not shukla yajurveda )

But, whats the content in Brahmanas? Whats it talks about majorly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find an English translation of the Taittiriya Shakha of the Krishna Yajur Veda?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31534/where-can-i-find-an-english-translation-of-the-taittiriya-shakha-of-the-krishna)

Comment: 'Taittirīya Brāhmaṇa, where can I purchase this?' - See [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/33711/2995) answer.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! You should not ask multiple questions in a single post. "If I want to buy......" question is edited out to avoid the issue.

Comment: i  am not looking for english translation, as i may get a different meaning/ understanding I.just wanna see original sanskrit version and i would like to buy that grantha!